# There isn't enough free memory to update the display. Close unneeded programs and try again. Access 2013 Report

Tags: ms-access, printing, report

I'm developing a database application in Access 2013. The operating system is Win10. I have created a report to print the receipt with WP T800 thermal printer. I can open the report but can't print or print preview this report.

When I set "Microsoft print to PDF" as default printer I can open, save receipt as PDF file or Print preview the receipt. When the default printer is WP T800 the above error occurs.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, where is your code? If not... well, it's off topic for SO

Comment: There is no problem with my code. running fine. I have problem with printing a Access report with the thermal receipt printer. I can just open the report, but cannot be printed.

Comment: And how are you opening the report? How are you printing it? Are you doing this with code?

Comment: DoCmd.OpenReport "receipt", acViewReport with this line I could open the report. then i added   DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrint to print the report. when the 2nd line is running the error occurs. then i right click on the report in the design pane and clicked on printpreview.

Comment: It seems like a printer driver issue.

Comment: I have already done "Print Test Page". It was fine. And im able to print word doc with this printer.  BTW Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I have found the cause of the error. When the paper size is set to 72mm(roll) the error comes. Now I set to 72mm(page). no error.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error message is relatively accurate but still vague enough to be a bit unclear.  Bottom line is there is too much going on.  As it advises - close some stuff.  For instance if there are other reports and forms open that could be closed.  Test that.  You might have to put in close commands for them as part of the code that opens this new report.

Closing excess reports or forms is the easiest fix if it works.  More challenging is an extremely complex stack of queries that are the record source for the report.  In this case you need to simplify - all sorting occurs in the report object so eliminate that from the queries that make up the report's data source.  If you have a lot of aggregate query action - you might have to consider writing those results off to a temp table as a first step in order to make the query set less complex.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. While printing report (receipt) the front form (frmFront),
And frmMonthlypass are open.
In the WHERE clause of the SQL I have put ;
WHERE (((Receipt.ReceiptNo)=[forms]![frmMonthlyPass]![txtReceiptNo]));
So the form frmMonthlypass also have to be open.
After I changed the paper size to 72mm(page) no more error (There is not enough free memory to update them display….), but the printer cuts paper immediately below the last line, i.e it doesn’t leave the bottom margin. And then cuts and throws a small piece of extra paper.